# Combine if and NR in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I've been trying to figure this silly thing with awk in the last hours but no luck so far.
I understand how to plot every second line, for example:

```
awk 'NR%2' file
```

and I also understand how to print a column based file if one column is within a specific range, for example:

```
awk '{if ($1 > 'yourvalue') print}' file
```

What I don't quite get is how to combine the two. 
In practize, if I have a file organized as:

```
1 3 6 8
2 8 4 5
3 9 8 7
4 7 3 5
5 7 3 6
6 2 4 6
7 1 4 7
8 3 2 1
9 7 5 3
10 4 5 6
11 8 2 5
```

how can I get, for example:

```
1 3 6 8
3 9 8 7
5 7 3 6
7 1 4 7
8 3 2 1
9 7 5 3
10 4 5 6
11 8 2 5
```

so return every two lines if column 1 is smaller than 7 and print normally the rest. 
I tried to combine everything in one single line but I always get errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the 2nd condition and use OR condition to combine them:

```
awk 'NR%2 || $1>=7' file
1 3 6 8
3 9 8 7
5 7 3 6
7 1 4 7
8 3 2 1
9 7 5 3
10 4 5 6
11 8 2 5
```

Comment: This seems to work but what happens if I want to print one line and delete the following two? For example:
1 3 6 8-
4 7 3 5-
7 1 4 7-
8 3 2 1-
9 7 5 3-
10 4 5 6-
11 8 2 5-

Comment: Well that one seems to be a different problem, isn't it? You should edit the question to show the input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine conditions using `&&` (and) and `||` (or).
You can use parentheses for nesting conditions.
For example:

```
awk 'cond1 && (cond2 || cond3)' file
```

This:

```
awk '{if ($1 > 7) print}' file
```

... is equivalent to this:

```
awk '$1 > 7 { print }' file
```

... because you can write conditions outside of the `{...}` to use as *filters*.

... which is equivalent to:

```
awk '$1 > 7' file
```

... because the default action is to print.